# shell script - attachment getting splitted in mail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm using mailx in a script to send a file to the recipient from a Linux machine.

If the text file has few lines, mailx is working fine for sending the file BUT, if the attachment file has too many lines, for example 346 lines, the mailx command is sending multiple mails by splitting the file into 7 parts like 50 lines, 50 lines...

how can I stop this from happening and always send a single email with one attachment?

uuencode $TEMP_PATH/tmpfile2 summary.txt > $TEMP_PATH/file1.txt

cat $TEMP_PATH/newmessage1.txt $TEMP_PATH/file1.txt | mailx -s "my subject line" ${mail_id}

#here newmessage1.txt will have the email body and file1.txt the summary data lines to send.

Comment: Doesn't look like you are sending any attachments based on the commands you have posted?

Comment: @RamanSailopal as mentioned in the end of the post , the file1.txt is the attachment

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

cat file1 file2 , like in your example, is sending to the stdout both results into one, then sending the result to the command after pipe

Example

```
$ more test1.txt
akdkdkdkd
$ more test2.txt
kikkkkkdidid
$ cat test1.txt test2.txt | more
akdkdkdkd
kikkkkkdidid
$
```

In your case, you are combining both newmessage1.txt and file1.txt into one single output, then sending the result to mailx. Perhaps there is a limitation in your environment or something, but I can tell you that for sure that is how cat works.

Instead of

```
cat $TEMP_PATH/newmessage1.txt $TEMP_PATH/file1.txt | mailx -s "my subject line" ${mail_id}
```

Use this

```
cat $TEMP_PATH/newmessage1.txt | mailx -s "my subject line" -a $TEMP_PATH/file1.txt ${mail_id}
```

Comment: if the syntax is wrong then why it it is sending the mail with attachment having 50 records successfully? and moreover if the attachment is having over 300 records, then also, sending mails by splitting the file by splitting

Comment: please, if the answer solves your problem, can you accept it ?